# Redirect input/output of a terminal to a gui in iOS JB

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, user-interface, compiler-construction

I'm writing a GUI C/C++ editor that also compiles source files for the iOS platform, using the GNU compiler that ships with Cydia.

It's going to be a Cydia app, so everything should work.

To compile files I need to run a terminal command line, and  I'm considering using the function "system()" because I can't think of anything else.

I'm now searching for a method to redirect somehow the output and the input of the terminal to a GUI but I don't really know where to begin.

I read that I maybe could use a pipe to do that but it doesn't really do what I need it to, since I need a "live" input and output from the terminal, not a `.txt` file with the terminal output only...

Hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Use `popen()`. Something like this:

```
const char *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"gcc -o %1$@.o %1$@.c", sourceFileName].UTF8String;

FILE *p = popen(cmd, "r");
size_t sz;
char buf[1024];

while ((sz = fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, p) != 0) {
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buf length:sz encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    textView.text = [textView.text stringByAppendingString:s];
    [s release];
}

pclose(p);
```

Comment: I didn't know about this %1$ format specifier. Learned something new today. Thank you!

Comment: Wasn't popen() only read or only write? I need a multidirectional input/output not a monodirectional one, that's the main problem...
My head is going nuts trying to solve this problem

Comment: @mir_ko If popen doesn't work, then nothing does. Maybe have a look at the source code of MobileTerminal on GoogleCode - it's a full terminal emulator, I'm sure it has similar functionality.

Comment: I'll ask the mobileterminal team if they can help me, and I guess that for now i'll abandon the idea of compiling, ill just create the editor.. :sigh:

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again but i've tried to put this code in my app but it doesn't work. Ive put a UITextView element but it doesn't output anything.. :/